# Different Android dates in emulator and real device

Tags: android, android-date

I'm experiencing a very strange problem with `Date` objects in Android,
when I run the following code I get different dates in the emulator and in the real device. (`str1` and `str2` come from the following json result
[json file](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/goog/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/json))

```
String str1="1450967458";
String str2="1450980000";
Date dstart=new Date((long)Long.parseLong(str1)*1000);
Date dend=new Date((long)Long.parseLong(str2)*1000);
     
Log.i("VILLANUEVA","START:"+dstart.toString());
Log.i("VILLANUEVA","END:"+dend.toString());
```

**Dates in real device:**

> ... I/VILLANUEVA: START:Thu Dec 24 15:30:58 CET 2015
>
> ... I/VILLANUEVA: END:Thu Dec 24 19:00:00 CET 2015

**Dates in emulator**(These are the correct dates)

> ...I/VILLANUEVA: START:Thu Dec 24 09:30:58 EST 2015
>
> ...I/VILLANUEVA: END:Thu Dec 24 13:00:00 EST 2015

It seems to be a difference of **6 hours** between the device and the emulator. I've tested with `Calendar` class and I get the same difference. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got different timezones CET(+1) and EST(-5)

Comment: what do i have to do then?

Comment: I don't know your requirements for the code :) If you want to just have the same time on your device and emulator, set in settings the same timeZone (date&time)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not a solution, each user of the app could have a different time zone

Comment: If you need the same time in code (for what reason?) you can instantiate Date and Calendar class with the same TimeZone. Or just use simply use the time since epoch.

Comment: perhaps you are right and there is no point to set the same time zone. Thanks for your answer.